# Redirect stdout and stdin to file

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

I can write to and read from a file:

```
echo a > b.txt
read c < b.txt
```

Is Bash able to do this implicitly? Something like:

```
<turn on implicit mode>
echo a
read c
<turn off implicit mode>
```

While “implicit mode” is on, all *stdout* goes to *b.txt* and all *stdin* reads
from *b.txt*. I tried:

```
exec > b.txt
```

but it only affects *stdout*.

Comment: `echo a | read c` ?!?

Comment: @Marged That won't work because `read` runs in a subshell, so its variable assignment doesn't persist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working off the responses here, I came up with this:

```
d=`tty`
exec >b.txt <b.txt
echo a
read c
exec >$d <$d
```

I also realized that it might be better to leave stdout and stdin alone:

```
exec 3>b.txt 4<b.txt
echo a >&3
read c <&4
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `exec` to redirect both stdin and stdout at the same time

```
exec > b.txt < b.txt
echo a
read c
```

I wasn't sure if this would read what it wrote, but I tested it and it works.

You can revert it by duping the original FDs in other FDs, and then restoring them when you're done.

```
exec 10<&0 11>&1 > b.txt < b.txt
echo a
read c
exec <&10 10<&- >&11 11>&-
echo $c
```

Comment: You can also save your current `tty` in a variable and use it to revert the redirections: `mytty=$(tty); ... ; exec > "$mytty" < "$mytty"`

Comment: @j.a. That assumes that output was originally directed to the tty. What if the script was being run with its output redirected?

Comment: Yes @Barmar, it assumes that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get `bash` to assume this behavior, particularly given that `b.txt` is the input of one command and the output of another. There are a number of solutions to similar problems, that may be applicable depending on your actual problem:

1. Assuming you mean in a script and not in interactive mode, you can redirect a group of commands using braces, which saves you from having to spell everything out. It won't work if you're trying to make `b.txt` both the source and the destination within the group of commands.

   ```
   {
     echo a
     read c
   } <b_in.txt >b_out.txt
   ```
2. If the fact that `b.txt` exists isn't important, you can just use a pipe, or a pipe with `tee`:

   ```
   echo a | read c
   echo a | tee b.txt | read c
   ```
3. If you need `b.txt` because it behaves as a file, you can also consider process substitution.

   ```
   command_that_takes_a_file <(echo a)
   command_that_takes_stdin < <(echo a)
   ```

Comment: 1 makes no sense; `read` should be getting its input from the same file that `echo` outputs to. 2 makes no sense, `c` will not exist once the pipe completes

Comment: Then process substitution is probably what you're looking for, which is why it's also in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a client/server that communicates via stdin/stdout, and I wanted to capture those streams.  Here's the bash script:

```
cat - | tee stdin.log | $cmd | tee stdout.log
```